# How to dynamically add a validation rule using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to dynamically add a validation rule to some dynamic controls using http://jqueryvalidation.org/ but its not working.

```
 $(".rtxt").each(function () {
             $(this).rules('add', {
                 required: true
             });
         });

 <input class='rtxt'  name='txtDocName' id='txtDocName' style='width:220px;' type='text' >
```

Don't know what i am missing here.

I can't use 'required' attribute as its not supported by IE9 so i will have to use jquery validation plugin.

Here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ed4fg1xo/

Also, i need to do validation on div click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // 1. prepare the validation rules and messages.
    var rules = {
        textbox1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        textbox2: "required",
        textbox3: "required"
    };
    var messages = {
        textbox1: {
            required: "textbox1 is required",
            minlength: "textbox1 needs to be at least length 2"
        },
        textbox2: "textbox2 is requried",
        textbox3: "textbox3 is required"
    };

    // 2. Initiate the validator
    var validator
        = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("FormToValidate",
            rules, messages);

    // 3. Set the click event to do the validation
    $("#DivIdName").click(function () {
        if (!validator.validate())
            return;

        alert("Validation Success!");
    });
});
```

Comment: where do i need to place $("#yourformname").validate();

I need to validate controls on div click event.

Comment: View this link:http://forums.asp.net/t/1884112.aspx?using+jquery+validation+plugin+for+div+instead+of+form

Comment: do i need to place  $("#yourformname").validate(); in div click event?

Comment: i am getting error message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQueryValidatorWrapper' is undefined" on var validator
             = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("form1",
                 rules, messages);

Comment: Load jquery-1.7.1.min.js before the jquery.validate plugins.